# MapView and black screen

Tags: android, dictionary

I noticed that creation of a MapView object takes a long time. It is about one sec, so if I have a mapview in my layout I always see black screen during setContentView execution (if mapview is defined in xml layout). I tried also to create this MapView manually but still MapView constructor is a slow one.

Is it possible to show some other window during map initialization to omit this black screen?

Comment: You could show a splash screen or a loading bar for 2 seconds, its a bit dirty but it would allow time for the map to load

Comment: I tried to show a progress activity but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display a message/Image/whatever you want in your layout at the mapView location and use another thread to construct the mapView.

By the way, do you insert overlays to your mapView at startup ? If it is the case, try to delay them.

Other idea : if your application do not show the map at startup, load the mapview in the background.